# Updating pgadmin to newer version

Tags: postgresql, version, pgadmin-4

I opened my PostgreSQL (pgadmin 4). Then, a pop up message showed:

> You are currently running version 7.4. However, there is a new version 7.6. Click here for more information.

I downloaded the pgadmin 7.6. However, it was asking me to choose from "install only for me (Recommended) and the other one is "Intall for all users".

- What is the difference between these two?
- If I am the only one using my workstation, should I click the first one or the other?
- Can I delete the previous version? How?

Comment: If you're the only user, it doesn't matter. It's just a slightly different setup process, probably this will skip setting up directory structure in each users home directory and only do it for you. Each app can install and handle multiple system users differently, so the specifics differ from app to app. Some apps are capable of in-place update, some install new versions side-by-side, copy your data/settings and just set the latest one as default. If that's the case, you should see different versions listed separately in your apps, and see them under different paths on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very straightforward process to upgrade your current pgadmin version to the latest one. Just follow along with the installer and choose to upgrade the current installation if prompted.
As for the option to install just for yourself or for all users, this is only pertinent if there are multiple users of your system. If there are multiple users, they will have separate user profiles which can be accessed when you start up your system. In your case, you are the only user so you can go ahead and select the "Install only for me (Recommended)" option.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciated your reply. Have a good one.